# Entrust with Laravel - Eloquent queries with conditional roles

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, entrust

I'm having single User eloquent model in my Laravel App:

I'll be using Entrust for roles.
Users can have multiple roles.

I already managed to get the User have multiple roles with same eloquent model **User** like this:

```
  public function company(){

    if($this->hasRole('admin')){

        return $this->hasOne('App\Company');

    }elseif($this->hasRole('member')){

           return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
     }

   }
```

How to handle this in other models suppose in **Company** model:

```
public function admin(){

    $this->hasOne('App\User'); //if has role admin
}

public function members(){

    $this->hasMany('App\User'); //if has role member
}
```

How to get this working?

**Edit**
I'm able to traverse through the users and get the related users with specific role but it adds null items in the collection:

```
public function admin(){

    return $this->hasOne('App\User')->get()->map(function($u){

        if($u->hasRole('admin') && $u != null){

            return $u;

        }

    });


}
```

Though, I'm checking the `$u != null` I can see many null objects in the collection.

Comment: You should add a `manages` relationship that will dynamically attached the relevant model

Comment: How to do that? Can you elaborate?

Comment: yeah multiple roles per user. And I'm using entrust which has a pivot table role_user table for multiple relations. There's no attribute in users table for role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed to make it work. However I'm not able to get the Relation object instead I'm getting collection of Users having role Admin

```
public function admin(){

    return $this->hasOne('App\User')->get()->map(function($u){

        if($u->hasRole('admin') && $u != null){

            return $u;

        }

    })->reject(function ($u){
        return $u == null;
    });


}
```

Comment: I'll accept another answer if it solves the problem more efficiently. Waiting till then this may help someone for now.